# Backward Navigation and Planning for Intent.Extras

Tags: android, back-button, extra

I'm working on my first app.  The app is basically just a series of forms used to populate a database.  I have two problems and I'm hoping someone with more experience can point me toward a solution.

To illustrate the issue, let's say I have three activities that a user will pass through to eventually create one record for the database.  The user enters two pieces of information on Activity1.  That information is saved as two intent extras and passed to the Activity2.  In Activity2, three more pieces of information are added and now five intent extras are passed to Activity3.  In Activity3, four more pieces of information are added and then all nine pieces of information get written to the database through a SQLite query.  As long as the user performs these actions in this order, everything is great.  The problems arise if the user has to navigate back to a previous activity to change or fix something.

Problem 1:
If the user adds new information in Activity2 and then wants to go back and fix something in Activity1, navigating back loses all of the new information because Activity1 originally didn't require any intents to be created.  If a user gets all the way to Activity3 and wants to go back to Activity1, then going back through Activity2 and Activity1 loses all of those intents.  I have somewhat addressed the problem by creating an if.intents.extra.exists statement to determine whether Activity1 is being opened from the original "start a new record" source or whether it was being navigated back from a future activity.  However, if the user only partially fills out Activity2, then a general if/then statement may not catch scenario.  Instead, I have had to write a separate if.intent.extras.exist statement for all potential intent extras that could be generated throughout the entire series of activities and put those in the onCreate lines for every single activity.  Moreover, even if a particular incoming intent.extra isn't being used for that form, I still have to unpack it, assign it to a string value, and then write it back to an intent.extra for the next activity.  Even though this approach technically works, I can't believe this is the "right" way of doing things.  Should I be using something other than intent.extras to pass this information between activities and to make forward and backward navigation less cumbersome?  As a side note, my app has a lot more than three activities, and I am tracking a lot more than nine pieces of information.

Problem 2:
When Activity1 originally loads, I use a date/time function to create a unique number for the record that will eventually be saved in the SQLite.  I use this number a lot throughout the rest of the forms.  It becomes part of the file name for pictures that are taken, the PDF report that gets generated, certain validation rules, e-mails that might be sent, etc.  This number is a pretty important part of the record.  Just like above, if the user navigates forward through the activities, everything is great; however, when the user has to naviagte backwards and winds up reloading Activity1, then this unique number gets overwritten and the record no longer has the same unique identifier as the picturefiles and other artifacts that may have already been created.  It potentially sets up this cascade of failures.  Just like above, I can kinda sorta address this problem with if/then statements, but as soon as I fix it in one place, I find it used in another method that causes a crash.  It seems like there should be a better way to generate a random or unique number and then protect it until you're really done with it.  Any advice?

For anyone who hasn't lost interest:
I just started learning java/android a few months ago.  I knew nothing about java previously and have no formal coding education.  Everything I've learned has been the result of watching youtube tutorials and searching for solutions to particular problems here (you guys are amazing, by the way).  Now that I know more, I'm realizing that my app is a complete mess that is basically just held together with chewing gum and duct tape--so much so that I am seriously considering starting over from scratch and rebuilding the entire thing with clearer vision from the start.  For instance, I have tons of textView elements throughout the app that display the project number, but I don't have a consistent naming convention to determine which of the seventeen various layouts I'm talking about when I search for resource IDs.  Are there any good sources out there that define a standard naming convention for variables, text fields, database fields, etc. when you have a lot of them or does everyone just make up their own?  What naming conventions do you follow?

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  That gives me a place to start looking.  I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Wow...what a huge question ! You know, *images speak louder than words* :)

Anyway...What you've described is not a very big problem, just an architecture misunderstanding. Let me explain you.

You're focused that If user follow the "right" path, everything is good. But if he goes backward, some informations are missing/erased. So, all you have to do is to save the information in a global manner. Let's say a Singleton or a DataManager (something like that) accessible from everywhere in your app.